# Duplicate Files on phone's storage (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

Hope you are fine what I am trying to achieve is to get all the duplications from the internal storage, for that, I am already using a method I don't know what I am doing wrong please have a look,

```
private fun getDuplicateItems() {
    var tempDuplicateItem: DuplicateItemModel
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        for (i in 0 until listOfAllFiles.size) {
            for (j in i until listOfAllFiles.size) {
                if(!File(listOfAllFiles[i].directoryPath).isDirectory && !File(listOfAllFiles[j].directoryPath).isDirectory ){
                    if (listOfAllFiles[i].fileName == listOfAllFiles[j].fileName && listOfAllFiles[i].fileSize == listOfAllFiles[j].fileSize &&
                                    !listOfAllFiles[i].fileName.endsWith(".tmp") && !listOfAllFiles[j].fileName.endsWith(".tmp") &&
                                    !listOfAllFiles[i].fileName.endsWith(".chck") && !listOfAllFiles[j].fileName.endsWith(".chck") &&
                                    !listOfAllFiles[i].fileName.startsWith(".") && !listOfAllFiles[j].fileName.startsWith(".")
                    ) {
                        tempDuplicateItem = DuplicateItemModel(
                                "$i${listOfAllFiles[i].fileName}",
                                listOfAllFiles[i].fileName,
                                listOfAllFiles[i].absolutePath,
                                listOfAllFiles[i].fileModificationDateAndTime,
                                File(listOfAllFiles[i].directoryPath).length(),
                                false,
                                false,
                        )
                        tempArrayListOfDuplicateItemsSingle.add(
                                DuplicateItemModel(
                                        "$i${listOfAllFiles[i].fileName}",
                                        listOfAllFiles[j].fileName,
                                        listOfAllFiles[j].absolutePath,
                                        listOfAllFiles[j].fileModificationDateAndTime,
                                        File(listOfAllFiles[j].directoryPath).length(),
                                        true,
                                        true,
                                )
                        )

                        tempArrayListOfDuplicateItems.add(
                                DuplicateItemArrayListItem(
                                        tempDuplicateItem,
                                        tempArrayListOfDuplicateItemsSingle
                                )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.invokeOnCompletion {
        var tempTotalDuplicateSize: Double = 0.0
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            progressBarDuplicateFiles.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            imageViewNextDuplicateFiles.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            for (x in 0 until tempArrayListOfDuplicateItems.size) {
                tempArrayListOfDuplicateItems[x].listOfDuplicationSubItems.forEach { duplicateItem ->
                    tempTotalDuplicateSize += duplicateItem.fileSize
                }
            }

              //UI Stuff

            textViewTotalSizeOfDuplications.text = "total Size of Duplicate Files (${HelperClass.readableFileSize(tempTotalDuplicateSize.toLong())})"
            textViewTotalFolderFilesDuplicateItem.text = "${tempArrayListOfDuplicateItems.size} Item(s)"
            relativeLayoutDuplicateItem.isClickable = true
        }
    }
}
```

I am using [MediaLoader](https://github.com/jiajunhui/MediaLoader), a library which gives me all the files on internal storage, and through those files, I am checking the data if the data is equal or not but getting the stream of data which I don't know is correct or not,

Comment: Instead of iterating twice the list, why don't you just use an object like LinkedHashSet<E>  which does not allow duplications and simply add file names there. Once it won't allow you to add (by returning false) you can then check this specific file information and see if it's duplicated

Comment: can you give me a simple example?

Comment: or just refer me to some link

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started:

```
File f = new File("your_relevant_path");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
HashSet<String> mHashSet = new HashSet<>();
   for (File currFile :
           files) {
       if (!mHashSet.add(currFile.getName()))
       {
            // Here there is a duplication of a file
       }
   }
```

Comment: `File f = new File('path');` will give me all the files or folders aswell ?

Comment: Yes, this will list everything. If you want to handle files within a folder, you should make a recursive function that checks if the file being parsed now is a directory and call the function on that directory as well